# Visual Studio Code cannot deploy to azure - Credentials Argument needs to implement signREQUEST

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions

I am getting "Credentials argument needs to implement signRequest method" when trying to "create a function app in azure" from Azure\resources\remote in VS Code. However, I can create a Resource Group from the same place. I validated that I can see the group in the portal.

Spent 5 hours searching this and trying everything I could find and / or think of. Just can't figure out why one works and the other doesn't.

It is preventing me from deploying the local test function (I'm going thru the az-204 Microsoft exercise, so I am a noobie at Azure)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the below steps help to fix the issue:

Go to Credential Manager in your system and delete the VS Code Sign-ins

[image]

and restart the VS Code > Re-login to your Azure Account from Visual studio code and perform the create function operation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Log in at https://portal.azure.com/ with a web browser and
   pass the two factor authentication. I think it's this need for two factor authentication that's glitching the VSC sign-in.
2. Choose Azure: Sign Out from the VSC command pallet.
3. Sign in to Azure again in VSC.